# Search contain in xml if found replace whole node

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout name="layout">
  <section name="Header">
    <placeholder name="headers" width="30" class="header">sam,pam</placeholder>
  </section>
  <section name="Content">
    <placeholder name="RightA" width="55">location</placeholder>
  </section>
</layout>
```

I want to replace whole node if its contain `sam`.Means if node contains `sam` I want to rewrite node:

```
<placeholder name="headers" width="4,5,91">sam,sam2,pam</placeholder>
```

instead of:

```
<placeholder name="headers" width="30" class="header">sam,pam</placeholder>
```

In c#:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string sFileName = @"FileNameWithPath";
doc.Load(sFileName );
foreach (XmlNode ....... )
{
    //Need help hear how to loop and replace.
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If the node contains sam what will you replace it with , is it sam,sam2,pam

Comment: Nop I want to replace whole node bcz `width="4,5,91"` is differ :(

Comment: @freebird `<placeholder name="headers" width="30" class="header">sam,pam</placeholder>` repalce with `<placeholder name="headers" width="4,5,91">sam,sam2,pam</placeholder>`.Any idea?Is it possible in c#?

Comment: Let me work it out it is possible .can you use Linq

Comment: I am unable to use Link sorry its my project demand :(

Comment: Ok Let me try I will get back to you.

Comment: You might want to state the LINQ requirement in the question. The only answer so far is using LINQ.

Comment: @Shree Can you try my answer.Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: @Shree Did it help you , please also upvote it if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.Load("Path");
 XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("section") ;

 foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
   {
      XmlNode childNode = node.SelectSingleNode("placeholder");
        if (childNode.Value.Contains("sam"))
          {
              childNode.Value = "sam,pam,sam2";
              childNode.Attributes["width"].Value = "4,5,91";

           }
   }

 xmlDoc.Save("Path");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an XDocument for better control over find and replace.

```
XDocument myDocument = XDocument.Load("path to my file");
foreach (XElement node in myDocument.Root.Descendants("placeholder"))
{
    if (node.Value.Contains("same"))
    {
        XElement newNode = new XElement("placeholder");
        newNode.Add(new XAttribute("header", node.Attribute("header").Value); // if you want to copy the current value
        newNode.Add(new XAttribute("width", "some new value"));
        node.ReplaceWith(newNode);
    }
}
```